# How should I solve generalized eigenvalue problems in Python? (Orr-Sommerfeld equation)

Tags: python, fluid-dynamics, ode, eigenvalues

I am trying to solve the [Orr-Sommerfeld equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orr%E2%80%93Sommerfeld_equation) numerically, using the techniques given in [this article](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Numerical-solution-of-the-Orr-Sommerfeld-equation-McBain-Chubb/e3ed3b990c378940faa86a9f47b430ae5d4ef852). This leads to solving a generalized eigenvalue problem, that is, given two matrices $\mathbf A,\mathbf B$ with possibly complex entries, we would like to find a pair $(\lambda,\boldsymbol v)$ where both $\lambda $ and $\boldsymbol v$ are possibly complex, satisfying
$$\mathbf A\boldsymbol v=\lambda \mathbf B\boldsymbol v\tag 1$$

Note that $\mathbf B$ is **not necessarily invertible**, i.e, we cannot (in general) simply multiply both sides by $\mathbf B^{-1}$ to reduce it to an ordinary eigenvalue problem. And, even if we could, these matrices $\mathbf A,\mathbf B$ are fairly large, say about $100\times 100$ (and $\mathbf B$ is, in practice, probably quite sparse), so this would probably be a waste of computational resources anyway.
(I would also like to add that in my application I am more interested in the eigenvalue $\lambda$ than I am in the eigenvector $\boldsymbol v$.)

A common way of solving this kind of generalized eigenvalue problem is with [generalized Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition#Generalized_Schur_decomposition), also known as "QZ decomposition" in which we write

$$\mathbf A=\mathbf {QS}\mathbf Z^* \\ \mathbf B=\mathbf {QT}\mathbf Z^*\tag {2}$$
Where $\mathbf Q,\mathbf Z$ are [unitary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix) and $\mathbf S,\mathbf T$ are upper triangular. (The asterisk denotes the conjugate transpose.) The eigenvalues of $(1)$ then can be given as the ratio of the diagonal entries of these two upper triangular matrices,
$$\lambda_i=\frac{T_{ii}}{S_{ii}}$$

---

### **Solving the problem numerically in python.**

Python's `scipy` package has the module `linalg.eig` , which, according to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html#scipy.linalg.eig), is able to solve generalized eigenvalue problems of the form of $(1)$. The right-hand-side matrix can be given in the optional argument `b`. The default value of this argument `b` is `None`, in which the module will solve the standard eigenvector problem, i.e $\mathbf B=\mathbf I$ in $(1)$.

However, the `scipy` package *also* includes the `linalg.qz` module, which, according to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.qz.html) is able to perform a decomposition of the form of $(2)$.

**My question**, is, would I be better off simply inputting my matrices $\mathbf A,\mathbf B$ as the `a` and `b` arguments into the `scipy.linalg.eig` module, or would I be better off first finding their Schur decompositions with `scipy.linalg.qz` and then inputting the matrices $\mathbf S,\mathbf T$ into `scipy.linalg.eig` separately, and setting the argument `b=None`? Which one is faster?

Thanks.

Comment: If sparsity is present as you mentioned, it might be worth a little time to explore the similar methods in scipy.sparse.linalg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The performance of the two methods should be very close, because `scipy.linalg.eig` internally calls Lapack's [`ggev`](https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html-3.6.1/d9/d8e/group__double_g_eeigen_gab3b93851a33e592f5705fdcbc876c186.html), which itself calls `hgeqz` to compute a QZ decomposition. So, typically, most of the CPU time will be spent inside the same `hgeqz` function anyway.

There are two main differences:

1. `ggev` uses a form of deflation that might increase the accuracy of the computed quantities, so it is better to use it rather than unscaled QZ. [point EDITed after a correction by thijssteel]
2. Some additional work is required to extract the eigenvectors from the QZ decomposition. If you only need the eigenvalues, you can skip that work by calling `scipy.linalg.eigvals` instead (or `eig` with `right=0`, which is the same thing).

Comment: small note, I believe the routine that does the scaling to increase the accuracy is disabled by default. It does not work as well for generalized eigenvalues as it does for standard eigenvalues. However, it will still check for deflatable eigenvalues before running QZ which can increase accuracy.

Comment: Thanks @ThijsSteel for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a number of misconceptions about numerical linear algebra. The biggest is 100x100 isn't large. Large matrices start somewhere in the 10000x10000 range. The second thing is that even though the inverse doesn't exist, you can still do a linear solve (and preserve sparsity). Specifically, you can just compute the eigenvalues of `B\A`.

Comment: I disagree about the second point. If $B$ is not invertible, the linear system $BX=A$ is solvable only in the least-squares sense, and typically this 'solution' will not preserve the generalized eigenvalues of the pencil.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is `B\A` ?

Comment: a linear solve.